# Minimizing L4/ L6/ L2N norm for linear regression

Tags: linear-algebra, regression

OLS regression minimizes the sum of the squared errors. The normal equation for an OLS for $L_2$ minimization is as follows: $$b= (A'A)^{-1}A'y$$

What would be the equation to minimize the $L_4$ norm for an overdetermined system. How would I derive generalizations for any arbitrary even norm such as $L_6$, $L_8$ and so on. This question is related to:

[Why least squares?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63238/why-do-we-use-a-least-squares-fit)

Not very familiar with matrix calculus so a gentle introduction would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know that much, but there might not be any closed-form solution. $L_2$ is easy because it has a simple derivative.