# Why Dirichlet's energy uses a **squared** norm?

Tags: calculus-of-variations

$E = \int_{\Omega}\left \| \nabla u(x)\right \|^2 dx$

So, Dirichlet's energy measures the integral of the squared norm of the gradient. Why squared norm? What would we get if we use just a norm? It's still going to be non-negative.

If I calculated a $u(x)$ that minimizes $E = \int_{\Omega}\left \| \nabla u(x)\right \| dx$ (not squared) would it be worse than Dirichlet? My goal is exactly what I specify: the gradient at any point should have minimum length.

Is the reason for the squared norm minimisation equivalent to the role of the square in the least squares fit? ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63238/why-do-we-use-a-least-squares-fit))

Comment: extremizing the squared norm is equivalent to extremizing the norm. Also $$
|\nabla {u}|^2 = \nabla u \cdot \nabla u
$$
to which the divergence theorem lends itself well.

Answer (score 4):

I think the square comes from physical modelling the bending energy.

But then, the square of a Hilbert space norm has several nice properties: it is uniformly convex and twice continuously differentiable with constant second derivative.

The Dirichlet problem
$$
\min \int_\Omega \frac12|\nabla u|^2 - uf \ dx
$$
is of course not equivalent to
$$
\min \int_\Omega |\nabla u| - uf \ dx.
$$
The latter problem is much harder to solve and analyze.

For instance, it is much more difficult to prove that the second problem has a solution with integrable gradient.

The minimizer of the Dirichlet energy satisfies
$$
-\Delta u = f,
$$
whereas the minimizer of the second problem satiesfies
$$
-\nabla\cdot\left( \frac{\nabla u}{\|u\|} \right) =f.
$$
To have a finite-dimensional analogue, consider the minimization of 
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \frac12|a_i|^2 - a^Tc
$$
and of
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n |b_i| - b^Tc.
$$
The first one has solution $a_i=c_i$, the second has a solution only if $|c_i|\le 1$ for all $i$ (which is then $b_i=c_i$).

Comment: I was talking about the Dirichlet energy, which is without -uf. I updated the question with more detail.

Answer (score -1):

I think in this form, the Dirichlet's energy is a strictly convex quadratic function and should have an UNIQUE minimum for reasonable boundary conditions .
This also holds for the least squared norm minimisation.